# Multiple notification -- android

Tags: android, performance

I am using alarm manager to display multiple local notification. The notification works fine, but the sequence of notification is happens only after i clear it from notification bar. The sequence is not happened.

code to pending intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        for(int i=0;i<milliSec.size();i++){     
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),(milliSec.get(i)), pendingIntent);
        System.out.println("Calling Alaram...");
```

Code to display notification

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     CharSequence from = "Sample Notification";
     CharSequence message = "Notification different milliseconds ...";
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,  new Intent(), 0);
     Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notification Test...", System.currentTimeMillis());
     notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
     notif.flags= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
     nm.notify(1, notif);
    }
```

How to do multiple notification sequence without clearing the existing message from notification. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this line of code

```
nm.notify( System.currentTimeMillis(), notif);
```

You have set it to 1 so every time it overrites notification

Answer (score 1):

You always passing same requestcode in intent. so just need to change request code.

```
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, request_code,  new Intent(), 0);
```

also need to change notify id.

```
nm.notify(change_notify_id, notif);
```